# Voice to Text javascript for VF or lightning

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, einstein

Need to find a way to convert voice to text in salesforce. I know we have web speech API available but it only works for chrome browser and doesn't work for IE browser. Any other options available to convert voice to test in salesforce. I need this option for browser.

Below option works but only for chrome.
http://www.0to1code.com/understanding-voice-recognition-search-using-visualforce/

Answer (score 1):

For now, you're pretty much limited to cloud-based APIs, such as [Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/transcribe/) or [Google](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=na-US-all-en-dr-bkws-all-all-trial-e-dr-1008076&utm_content=text-ad-none-any-DEV_c-CRE_291204615810-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20AW%20SEM%20%7C%20BKWS%20%7C%20US%20%7C%20en%20%7C%20EXA%20~%20ML/AI%20~%20Speech%20API%20~%20Speech%20to%20Text%20~%20Google%20Speech%20To%20Text-KWID_43700036257547072-kwd-475108782129&utm_term=KW_google%20speech%20to%20text-ST_Google%20Speech%20To%20Text&gclid=Cj0KCQjwhtT1BRCiARIsAGlY51K3An35Ueu-BNkPVMDn_FFesYbcl0rkfPgxV1--98H9ipG6MylNewsaAjInEALw_wcB)'s APIs. These APIs have per-month costs and a limit to how many requests can be processed within various time windows. Google Chrome is the only browser that supports the [Speech Recognition API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API/Using_the_Web_Speech_API) at this time. This is why the article you linked to only supports Google Chrome.